# Lowenheim-Skolem theorem confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

This Wikipedia entry on the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) says:

> In mathematical logic, the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, named for Leopold Löwenheim and Thoralf Skolem, states that if a countable first-order theory has an infinite model, then for every infinite cardinal number κ it has a model of size κ.

What does the "size" of a model referring to (or mean)?
Edit: If it is referring to the cardinality of a model (set), how do you get the cardinality of one model (-> It's synonymous with interpretation, right?)? What is inside the model, then? I mean, it seems sensical to define a model of a language, as a language has some constant numbers and objects, but defining a model of a single object - a number - seems nonsensical to me. What is inside the model of an infinite number?

Thanks.

Comment: The cardinality of the underlying set.

Comment: @plm I edited the question.. can you help me more? Thanks.

Comment: The way this question is phrased shows a lot of confusion.  I think what is needed is not just straightening out some particular error, but rather learning the definitions from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each model has a set of individuals. The size of the model is the cardinality of this set.

Comment: So, what are the individuals? Isn't an infinite number a sole individual?

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of your confusion, but the word "it" towards the end of your Wikipedia quote refers to the countable first-order theory, not to the infinite cardinal number.  "It has a model of size $\kappa$" means that the theory has a model of size $\kappa$, i.e., a model whose underlying set is a set of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: @Ted Thanks - that's where I got confusion... stupid me...